# How to create multiple HTML tables in logic app using 'Create HTML table' and 'Compose' activities?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a scenario where multiple variables will be passed from ADF to logic apps. The variables hold JSON content and it needs to be converted to tables and added to mail content.

Could someone explain how I can receive variables from logic app, transform each variable to HTML table and add it to mail content.

Comment: Please check link by chatgpt https://chat.openai.com/share/78c3897a-f0d1-4231-b964-4b369c33ce80

Comment: Can you provide input variables and provide expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`NOTE:`**

Variable inputs need to be in JSON and then should be transformed into JSON array as **`Create HTML Table`** action in Logic apps takes only JSON array as an input.

**`Example Input:`**

```
[{"id": 8,"name": "Rithwik","email": "Rithwik@example.com"},{"product": "lappy","price": 10,"quantity": 1},{"title": "Task","description": "Some Task","status": "Working"}]
```

Here I have taken three different table inputs.

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then in For Each:

[image]

Then send an email:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "value": "<style>\n#testID table, table th, table td {border: 1px solid #0000FF}\n</style>\n<div id=\"testID\">\n@{body('Create_HTML_table')}\n</div>\n\n***********************************************************************************\n"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Create_HTML_table": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    },
                    "Create_HTML_table": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "format": "HTML",
                            "from": [
                                "@items('For_each')"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Table"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('var1')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var1",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "email": "Rithwik@example.com",
                                    "id": 8,
                                    "name": "Rithwik"
                                },
                                {
                                    "price": 10,
                                    "product": "lappy",
                                    "quantity": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "Some Task",
                                    "status": "Working",
                                    "title": "Task"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{variables('var2')}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "IMPORTANT",
                        "To": "v-rbojja@microsoft.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/v-rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```